How do I get my free Far Cry Blood Dragon Classic Edition?
I bought Far Cry 6: Gold Edition from the PS Store on PS4 (Pro) a few months back and only now realised that, as well as most DLCs, it says I get Far Cry Blood Dragon Classic Edition for free, but I have no idea how to get it for free. I can't find anything in connect or the in-game store, and the game on the PS Store is priced and asks for payment.
There are no details included on how to actually get the free game, so...
How do I get my free Far Cry Blood Dragon Classic Edition?

Did you buy the game only or the season pass? The season pass is what gets you the DLC and Blood Dragon by the looks of it https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/game/far-cry/far-cry-6/season-pass

Oh, I thought I put that, sorry, I bought the Gold Edition With all DLC except Lost Between Worlds. Everything else it says in the description, I got (and completed, btw ;)).

Everything I am finding on the internet says it should be a separate item in the PlayStation store that should be available to you for free.  Perhaps try again?  Does the season pass have to be "installed" separately from the game also? I wouldn't think so, but Idk how PlayStation does things.

You don't need PS-Plus active, do you? Just thinking because mine ran out just before I tried. I'll try again tonight.

OK, I got it.
In the versions drop-down menu of the game page in the PS Store, there are paid versions and free versions.
BUT... The free versions say you have to have PS Plus Extra or PS Plus Premium.
I haven't even got PS Plus Essentials right now, but I gambled and selected Free - [PS Plus Extra symbol] and waited for it to take me to the sign-up screen... but it didn't, it just showed me a Download button, so five minutes later, I was laughing at the brashly humorous campaign tutorial in...
Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon Classic Edition.
(btw, it's like 90% better than I was expecting!)
